# Why wrap text around the figure is not woking?

Tags: html, css

As I have read from a [website](https://www.uvm.edu/~bnelson/computer/html/wrappingtextaroundimages.html), I try to wrap a paragraph text around a image. Am a newbie to html!!! I think this must be a small correction in the code.

But I am failed to do that..

```html
<div style="width: 100%; float: left;"> 
<img src="http://www.postalwebplus.com/yahoo_site_admin/assets/images/Passport-Photo.300110653_std.jpg" alt="left" width="150px" >
 
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
```

### How to get rid off this?

thank you for helping!!!

I want the text should wrap exactly some thing [like this.](http://www.jwf.us/projects/jQSlickWrap/example1.html)

Comment: What do you want to receive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `align="left"` to your image.

```html
<div style="width: 100%; float: left;"> 
<img src="http://www.postalwebplus.com/yahoo_site_admin/assets/images/Passport-Photo.300110653_std.jpg" align="left" width="150px" >
 
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have added alt =left ..function of alt attribute is to display some alternate text in absense of the image. other than that you adjust need to adjust your image to left or right as you need.

```html
<div style="width: 100%; float: left;"> 
<img src="http://www.postalwebplus.com/yahoo_site_admin/assets/images/Passport-Photo.300110653_std.jpg" alt="left" align="right" width="150px" >
 
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Shivkumar...You are helping me a lot... without much knowledge about the coding... I am designing one of our conference web.. Thanks a lot.. if you are free.. kindly check this web and gives comments to improve the web.. www.iclaa2017.com